# How to write this conditional request correctly MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I need to check if a book rating for specific book from specific person exists.
If it does update it, if it doesnt create it.
I am getting a whole bunch of wrong errors for 9th 10th.... 12th parameter missing while I count only 8
My mariaDB version is 10.5.8-MariaDB.
My code:

```
const createBookRate = async (userId, bookId, rate) => {
    const sql = `
    SELECT IF(EXISTS( SELECT * from rates WHERE rates.users_id=? AND rates.books_id=? ),
    UPDATE rates SET rates.rate=? WHERE rates.users_id=? AND rates.books_id=?,
    INSERT INTO rates(users_id, books_id, rate))
    VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
    `
    const { insertId } = await pool.query(sql, [userId, bookId, rate, userId, bookId, userId, bookId, rate])
    const rateEntry = await getBookRate(insertId)
    return rateEntry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` inside the `IF` clause of a `SELECT` statement, those must be performed separately.

To perform this in a safe manner, use a transaction and first lock the selected row with [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for-update/), then either `UPDATE` or `INSERT` it and finally `COMMIT` the transaction.

If the table has a primary key, you can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/) to either insert the row or update it, depending on whether it exists or not. This allows everything to be done in one step without having to first select the affected rows.